The Docker Desktop Unexpected WSL error Windows 10
I'm having trouble while running Docker Desktop. I have attached the screenshot of Docker Desktop.
I have updated the WSL 2.2.4.0 and enabled the Windows features like Hyper -v, Windows Hypervisor Platform, Container still the problem persist.
I have also tried the recommended steps include shutting down WSL using wsl --shutdown, rebooting the computer, or reinstalling WSL/Docker.

